# What is the capacitor needed for 30 kHz power rectifier?

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

I need to rectify 200 V at 30 kHz for a resistive load of 3-4 kW. I use a 1200 V/60 A Schottky diode bridge. I have some 6800 uF/450 V capacitors. Can I use them, or should I use other values? Is there any formula to compute other values (voltage, frequency, load)?

Wave form - not sure, but not sinus.
Output ripple - not important, as long the load is resistive. Capacitor is only for optimizing the output.

So, I should test the rectifier with increasing loads, in order to keep in the diode-s range. Should I test the bridge with the 6800 capacitors?

Comment: Welcome! What's your input voltage waveform? Sine? Square? What's your output voltage ripple requirement? Have you tried to simulate your circuit?

Comment: Have you tried simulating your circuit to see what ripple voltage you get and what is acceptable?

Comment: What is the reason to feed the resistive load buffered DC?

Comment: With DC I can measure the output voltage. With AC al 30KHz, I do not have oscilloscope, nor an adapter for DMM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simulation with some components values ... (without specs).

The diode bridge should withstand some kA for "some" millisecond (starting phase ...) ...
and then +/- 120 A peak ...

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It is recommended to consider several factors, including current requirements, input and output voltage fluctuations, load characteristics, and required ripple levels. You can estimate the required capacitance using the following simplified formula:

C=I⋅ΔVf⋅VrC=f⋅Vr​I⋅ΔV​

in:

```
 C: C is the required capacitance in farads.
 I: I is the load current in amps.
 ΔV: ΔV is the desired output voltage ripple in volts.
 f: f is the switching frequency in Hertz.
 Vr: Vr​ is the rated voltage of the capacitor in volts.
```

Comment: Why is Vr included? Is C=I*DV*f*Vr*C correct? Thank you.

Comment: (Down-voters please comment what in particular makes a post *not useful*.)

Comment: @greybeard - Hi, Please note that, as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121350), downvoters do not have to explain their votes.

Comment: FredMorgan - Analysis suggests your answer may have been copied from elsewhere. [This site rule](/help/referencing) explains that any content copied or adapted from elsewhere must be correctly referenced. || Therefore, if your answer *was* copied from elsewhere, please [edit] it and add the required reference to the source. If it was *not* copied from elsewhere, please [edit] it and explain the formula you gave, as it does not seem correct. Thanks.